# Why it only retrieve last line of the text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a few text files that have multiple lines. I am trying to read through all the lines in the text files using below code, but it only returns the last sentence of each text file.

1st text file :

```
Successful Download
FTP DOWNLOADING
ERROR-20140605CW19
```

2nd text file :

```
Succesful Download
DisConnected
```

The below code is used to to find specific keywords so it will perform some action in the `if else`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM (
cd C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Scriptlogs\3535-2D\
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%e in ('findstr /B "DisCo ERROR null DOWNLOADING" log_DP_*.txt') do (

   echo %%e    <------- this always return the last line of the text files.
   SET x=%%e
   SET s=!x:~0,5!
   SET ddate=!x:~6,8!
   SET cf=!x:~25,4!
   SET week=!x:~14,5!
   SET ddate2=!x:~17,8!
   SET folder=!x:~13,4!
   SET NS=!x:~4,11!

   REM (
   REM echo(s=!s!
   REM echo(ddate=!ddate!
   REM echo(cf=!cf!
   REM echo(week!week!
   REM echo(ddate2=!ddate2!
   REM )>&2
   IF "!s!" == "DisCo" IF NOT "!cf!" == "null" (
      echo(Downloaded:!ddate2!:3535-2D-!folder!
   )
   IF "!s!" == "DisCo" IF "!cf!" == "null" (
      echo(EmptyFiles:!ddate2!:3535-2D-!folder!
   )
   IF "!s!" == "ERROR" IF NOT "!NS!" == "DOWNLOADING" (
      echo(NoneFolder:!ddate!:3535-2D-!week!
   )
   IF "!s!" == "ERROR" IF "!NS! == "DOWNLOADING" (
          echo(FailedDownload
       )
    )
```

I need to get the 2nd to last sentence `FTP DOWNLOADING` so I able to perform my `if else` statement.

Why does `%%e` always return the last sentence of text file only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `findstr /b` option only matches strings at the *beginning* of the line. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) for details.

`DOWNLOADING` is *not* at the beginning of the line. `ERROR` *is,* which is why you're finding that particular line.

You'll either have to adjust what you're looking for (such as `FTP` instead of `DOWNLOADING`) or get rid of the `/b` so it looks in the entire line - that, however, may have other consequences you should watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Use "tokens=2,*"

So that all 2nd tokens  in every possible line (*) are passed to the for body with

tokens 2 as %%e
tokens * as %%f

Hope that helps ...